# Drupal View with Taxonomy Argument Display

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a view with an argument based on Taxonomy Term and a page display.  I get a nice summary list on the display, but I'd like to show an image and the taxonomy term.  Any way to do this non-programatically?

Currently the page looks like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [shaiperednik.com](http://shaiperednik.com/img/current_products_view.png))</sub>

I'd like something like this: (just an idea, exact layout is irrelevant at this point)
[image]
<sub>(source: [shaiperednik.com](http://shaiperednik.com/img/example_layout.png))</sub>

I have the taxonomy_image module installed, images uploaded for the necessary terms, but can't figure out how to get them displayed on the argument summary page
I've also followed the how to @ http://drupal.org/node/638578#comment-2799854, but don't know what to do after step 7. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found my solution. Created a taxonomy view of the products vocab as a grid linking images and text fields to their taxonomy pages and BAM it worked!

Comment: You can accept your own answer so the question doesn't appear as unanswered. It suckered me in to looking at your question to try to answer it!

Comment: StackOVerflow's forcing you to wait before accepting your own answer made me forget about it entirely.